# changing image based on free/busy call

Tags: javascript, php, css

I want to show when a business is "opened or closed" by displaying "open" and "closed" images. The trick is, I want the information to be taken based on a free/busy call coming from a Google calendar. So far, the page is pulling the correct information in and of itself- the problem is that when I've parced the data with the JavaScript, the CURRENT time is correct, END time of the "busy" event is correct, however the start time is displaying 6 hours before it's supposed to and I can't figure out why or how to correct it.

So the PHP is currently:

```
<!-- Google Calendar for  The Commons -->
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
$request = array(
'items' => array(
    array('id' => 'REMOVED FOR PRIVACY'),
),
'timeMin' => date('c'),
'timeMax' => date('c', strtotime('+2 month')),
);
$curl = curl_init();
$options = array(
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 10,
CURLOPT_POST           => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => json_encode($request),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen(json_encode($request))
),
CURLOPT_URL            =>
'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy?fields=calendars&key=REMOVED FOR PRIVACY',
CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10;rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0',
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
 $result = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 echo $result;
```

And then it links well to the JavaScript and clearly its providing all the information.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.get("/dining-new/admin/php/commonsgcalendar.php", function (data) {
    var currenttime = Date();
    var nowDate = parseInt(currenttime.substring(8, 11));
    var nowHour = parseInt(currenttime.substring((16, 18)) - 4 ) * 60;
// its in GMT so to get EST I'm subtracting 4 hours then changing everything into minutes by multiplying by 60
    var nowMin = parseInt(currenttime.substring(19, 21));
    nowMin = (nowHour - 240) + nowMin;

    var firststart = data.indexOf("start");
    var startdate = parseInt(data.substring((firststart + 17), (firststart + 19)));
    var startHour = parseInt(data.substring((firststart + 20), (firststart + 22)) - 4) * 60;
    var startMin = parseInt(data.substring((firststart + 23), (firststart + 25)));
    startMin = (startHour - 238) + startMin;

    var endDate = parseInt(data.substring((firststart + 53), (firststart + 55)));
    var endHour = parseInt(data.substring((firststart + 56), (firststart + 58)) - 4) * 60;
    var endMin = parseInt(data.substring((firststart + 59), (firststart + 61)));
    endMin = (endHour - 240) + endMin;

     var areWeOpenNow = true;=
     if (nowDate != startdate) {
       areWeOpenNow = false;
    } else {
     if ((startMin <= nowMin) && (nowMin  <= endMin)){
        areWeOpenNow = true;
      }
    }
         if (areWeOpenNow) {
            $('.areweclosedfive').removeClass('areweclosedfive');
            $('#commonsselect').addClass('weAreOpened');
        }       
    });
});
```

As I said, the function is overall working. If the time is 2:01 est and the event ended at 2:00pm est- the sign shows closed. If it's 1:30 est and the event start was at 1:00 est and event ends at 2:00 est, it shows opened. If the event start is a at 8 pm est and the time is 2:00pm est, it shows that its closed.  **But if the start time is somewhere betweeon 0 and 6 hours into the future, the data is coming back saying that the event "busy" and displays the business as "opened" even though it shouldn't open/be busy for hours.**

I know that the data itself is coming back with numerical information, and that I'm using the same method to parce for the start time as I am the current time and end time, so I guess I'm just not seeing where the problem is coming in.

Answer (score 3):

*Part 1)*

If the data is coming over offset to another timezone you might want to adjust it on the way in.  Either to your timezone, or to say GMT.  The default timezone dictates how date/time functions will work, they do not magically convert dates and times.  You need to handle that using the known offsets.

What you want to watch out for are things like:

```
 var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
```

You might want to consider passing in that value from PHP, and not the client.  The issues with TZ arise in performing calculations.  Otherwise its just a representation of some point in time.

*Part 2)*

This looks like a wrong comparison:

```
if ("start" < currentTime && currentTime < "end")
```

Assume you want `start` from the `data` object.  So... `data.start`... Not 100% clear on structure of that object/array.  Use your `console.log` calls to make sure your comparison is kosher.  Feel like maybe you are missing a loop there too? Is `data` not a collection of slots?  Otherwise the approach looks good.

Comment: That's one of the things that I was thinking, how would I correct it?

Comment: I was going to say the same thing but is it looks like you are comparing a string instead of the value